# Is there a Typescript function to set the max char limit to a string and make it cut from a specific character?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

so i had a code like this..

```
const array = ['• foo', '• bar', '• third']
```

and many more elements in this array..
(the array was taken from a docs api so it was unpredictable everytime but always had a bullet at the start of elements)
then i joined the array using `.join('\n')`
so In the new string which came, now i wanted it to have a max characters of 1000, so i used a substring method on it, `.substring(0, 1000)`..
but the problem here was that sometimes, it cut lines in half.. like this

```
const string = array.join('\n').substring(0, 1000)
```

`string = "• foo\n• bar\n• th"`
so the rest of the word "third" was cut down... is there anyway i can keep a max limit on the string of 1000 and make it cut from the bullet closest to 1000?
so like it would only make it
`string = "• foo\n• bar"`

Comment: Why don't you write one?  Split the string into words, and then take words from the resulting array until you reach your character limit.

Comment: You could perform a `reduce()` on the array, reducing the values to a single string, so long as the max length has not been reached

Comment: If the first one is already longer than 1000 characters, do you want an empty string as output? Or is it safe to assume that that never happens? Also, why is the limit 1000 characters – limitations of some system, an approximate cutoff where some kind of excerpt is visually too long, …? This kind of thing might have implications on how you want to count. For example, a JavaScript string with `length === 1000` can fit only 90 instances of the ‍‍‍ emoji, but that represents 2,250 UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @Ry- Hi! So yea it is safe to assume that the first one will never exceed 1000 characters... and the limit is 1000 characters is because i am making something which doesnt support more than 1000 characters and i cannot do into detail yet

Comment: @CyberKnight: See edit about emoji and UTF-8. An example of a system limitation would be a database column with a type like `varchar(1000)`, a URL that needs to fit several parameters, or some external web API. You may want to match the counting method to whatever imposes the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const stringifyArrayToCharactersNumber = (
    arr: string[],
    charactersNum: number,
) => {
    return arr.reduce((resultString, arrayItem) => {
        const str = resultString + arrayItem + '\n';

        if (str.length <= charactersNum) {
            return str;
        }

        return resultString;
    }, '');
};
```

Use the function above to truncate to any numbers of characters: `const lessThan1000 = stringifyArrayToCharactersNumber(array, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate backwards through the characters in the string, starting at the end, and grab the index of the last bullet. Then use that index in `substring`. Something like:

```
const array = ['• foo', '• bar', '• third'];
const initialString = array.join('\n');
let bulletIndex = initialString.length - 1;

for (let i = initialString.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (initialString[i] === "•") {
        bulletIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

const finalString = initialString.substring(0, bulletIndex);
```

Note that that code doesn't quite do what you're saying: currently it cuts off everything after the last bullet, whether you want it to or not, so you'll need to add a check that the string is actually too long in the first place. But this basic approach should work.